# Constructors passing same int?

Tags: java

Suppose I have 2 buttons:
"Submit" & "Reset"

How do I make the constructors from the mouselistener to refer to one and the same int, so that everytime I press submit it reads and outputs the number of times submit has been pressed and at the same time when I click reset, the same int resets, so if I want to submit again, I'll start from 0 as before.

I hope you got the idea, I have everything written, I just dont know how to make the 2 constructors refer to 1 and the same int object, so thats my question!
If we have constructors:
public Submit(JTextField field, int..) and public Reset(JTextField field,Submit)
How do I refer to the int?

Thanks in advance to those of you attempted to answer it!!!

Comment: Show us what you have so far! It's better in my opinion, if someone helps you out with your existing code, than if someone writes it for you! You will learn more from it.

Answer (score 2):

You can use an `AtomicInteger` which is also thread safe. Or you need a model class which may contain the int counter and methods to increment and read the value:

```
public class Model {
  private int submitCount = 0;

  public void submit() {
    ++submitCount;
  }

  public void reset() {
    submitCount = 0;
  }

  public int submitted() {
    return submitCount;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a few ways to handle this, but I'd suggest looking at `AtomicInteger`, which is a mutable wrapper class for an `int` value.